# In Java, how to solve the error that XXXX cannot be solved as variable?

Tags: java

in the mothod of shoot below, for the two varibles 'hmm' and 'sequences' in the for loop, it always shows error that they cannot be solved as variable, but obviously I have declared them in the 'if' body at the upper part of this method. Why doesn't it recognize 'hmm' and 'sequences'?

```
public Action shoot(GameState pState, Deadline pDue) {
        int totalBirdsOfThisRound=pState.getNumBirds();
        boolean HMMinitialized=false;
        if (!HMMinitialized){
            HMM[] hmm=new HMM[totalBirdsOfThisRound];
            initializeHMM(pState,hmm);
            HMMinitialized=true;
            Vector<Integer>[] sequences=(Vector<Integer>[]) new Object[totalBirdsOfThisRound];
        }
        for(int i=0;i<totalBirdsOfThisRound;i++){
            Bird aBird=pState.getBird(i);
            for(int j=sequences[i].getLength();j<aBird.getSeqLength();j++)
                sequences[i][j]=aBird.getObservation(j);
            hmm[i].estimateModel(sequences[i]);
            int lastMove=aBird.getLastObservation();
            double[] currentStateDistribution=new double[10];
            Arrays.fill(currentStateDistribution, 0);
            currentStateDistribution[lastMove]=1;
        }
        return cDontShoot;
    }
```

Comment: You need to declare them **outside** the scope of the `if` statement. Variables are viable only in their scope of declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Java has block scope. You can only access a variable within the block that it was declared in. Usually a block starts with `{` and ends with `}`. But if/while/for with no braces together with the following line can also make up a block. So for `hmm` to be available inside the `for` loop you need to declare it in the block that contains the `for` loop.

Here is a hierarchical view of the blocks in your code:

```
shoot
    hmm // Accessible in for-loop if it's declared here
    if-statement
        hmm // Not accessible if it's declared here
    for-loop i
        for-loop j
```

Comment: You might confuse OP with this answer, because curly braces are not mandatory as "scope boundaries" (when the scope consists of a single expression). The inner `for` loop in the code above is a good example.

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing `HMM[] hmm` in the if condition and if control does not reach inside it would not have been initialized. So put this outside if condition like:

```
HMM[] hmm = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The HMM array is out of scope. Either declare the HMM array outside of the if block or move the for loop into the if block to solve this.